# dd_in_ear_load_EXC_ when deploing with JENKINS while the same EAR successfully deployed with WAS admin console

Tags: jenkins, websphere

I have an EAR file that can be deployed with the IBM WAS admin console successfully, but error out if deployed with JENKINS, was admin scripts, e.g. AdminApp.update:

**exception information:**

com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException: com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException:  [Root exception is org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: **dd_in_ear_load_EXC_**]
org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: **dd_in_ear_load_EXC_**

Since I am deploying the same EAR file to the same app server, i don't believe that application.xml and web.xml may be causing it.

What else i should check?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved.

Compatibility of the `JDK` versions causes this issue.

The JDK version of the compiler is 1.8, while the wsadmin.sh was using a lower version.

EAR deployed successfully after adding the option `"-javaoption -Djava.version=1.8"` in the command line.